# Odata $select nested model not work

Tags: class, select, odata

I got a problem when try to select a property as a class. When I get the whole properties (without $select), it works correctly.

But if I use the $select with the class property, no error but that property does not return.

> GetByIds?$select=ItemId,Pick

Pick is not return. Only ItemId.

```
public class ItemNotification : Entity
{
    public ItemNotificationSetting Pick { get; set; }
    public ItemNotificationSetting Receive { get; set; }
    public string ItemId { get; set; }
}

public class ItemNotificationSetting
{
    public bool IsEmail { get; set; }

    public bool IsNotification { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my builder

```
modelBuilder.EntitySet<ItemNotification>("ItemNotifications");
```

Thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`Pick` is a navigational property. You need to `$expand` it.

```
GetByIds?$expand=Pick&$select=ItemId
```

> When I get the whole properties (without $select), it works correctly.

Is `Pick` included even if you do not `$expand` it? If so, let me know because then there's probably something else that's wrong. By default, navigational properties are not included.

Comment: Thanks you for quick reply, but **Pick** is not a navigation property. So cannot be **$expand**. You see that, **Pick** does not have ID or key there.

Comment: @Marcus - Is `Pick` included in the results if you do not use `$select` at all?

Comment: Yes :) That's the strange thing. The result looks like this { "ItemId":"123", "Pick":{ "IsEmail": true, "IsNotification": false}}

Comment: @Marcus - Do you get any error when you use `$expand`?

Comment: Yes, It said that Pick is not an entity model